# Is data secure as long as you send it from/to an HTTPS page? I can still see form data in chrome's network devoloper tools

Tags: javascript, html, ssl, https

The form was sent from https://www.numbersgate.com/batchpixel/signUp.php

I just want to know if all I have to do to ensure security is send from https to https.

[image: IS IT SECURE!?]

Comment: Can you clarify your question at all? Of course the client can see it; there wouldn't be much point if it was encrypted from the user...

Comment: @Bandrami Just wanted to know if the data will be encrypted after it gets sent.  AKA if someone sniffs the packet, will they see
username: test3
password: test3
email: test3
or will they see encrypted gibberish?

Answer (score 2):

https secures only the connection from the user to the server. Once they are at the server they are no longer protected by https against attacks, so you have to find others ways to protect them there. https will also not protect the data from against attacks against the logic of the web application, like CSRF, XSS, clickjacking etc. In short: https is just one part to secure the data, there is much more.